# How to open the browser in collapsed form?

Tags: autoit

The code:

```
Local $iPID=ShellExecute("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe", "","","", @SW_MINIMIZE);
```

How to open the browser in collapsed form?

Answer (score 0):

```
; Optional debugging feature.
Opt('TrayIconDebug', True)

; Run Firefox if not running.
If Not ProcessExists('firefox.exe') Then
    ShellExecute('"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"')
EndIf

; Wait for a window to match the class.
WinWait('[CLASS:MozillaWindowClass]')

$hFirefox = 0
$iAbort = 5

Do
    Sleep(1000)

    ; Get all class windows into an array.
    $aWList = WinList('[CLASS:MozillaWindowClass]')

    For $i1 = 1 To UBound($aWList) -1
        ; Get the visible window from the window handle.
        If BitAND(WinGetState($aWList[$i1][1]), 2) Then
            $hFirefox = $aWList[$i1][1]
            _WinState($aWList[$i1][1], $aWList[$i1][0], True)
            ExitLoop 2
        Else
            _WinState($aWList[$i1][1], $aWList[$i1][0], False)
        EndIf
    Next

    $iAbort -= 1
Until Not WinExists('[CLASS:MozillaWindowClass]') Or $iAbort = 0

; Minimize the visible window.
If WinSetState($hFirefox, '', @SW_MINIMIZE) Then
    ConsoleWrite('A Firefox window has been minimized.' & @CRLF)
EndIf

Exit

Func _WinState($hWinHandle, $sWinTitle, $bWinVisible = False)
    ; Debug output for visible state of a window.
    Local $sWinVisible = $bWinVisible ? 'True' : 'False'
    ConsoleWrite(StringFormat('Handle: %s  Visible: %-5s  Title: %s', $hWinHandle, $sWinVisible, $sWinTitle) & @CRLF)
EndFunc
```

Even if you set a Firefox shortcut to minimize and use it
to start Firefox, Firefox may not minimize at startup.
This is why the show flag of `@SW_MINIMIZE` for the
[ShellExecute](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ShellExecute.htm) function may not work.

A `-tray` argument exists though I cannot get it to work as
mentioned in [Command Line Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Command_Line_Options#-tray).

To minimize at startup, the code provided may help.
It will find the 1st window that is visible of the class
`MozillaWindowClass`, and will attempt to minimize it.
The variable `$hFirefox` may contain the handle of the
visible Firefox window which can be used after the `Do`
loop has complete.

Some code is optional, i.e. `_WinState()` is used to output
debug information to console to know if the the window search
for the visible window is working OK.